# How to count the unique duplicate values in each column

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

We have the following dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A': [1,2,3,3,2,4,5,3],
                     'B': [9,6,7,9,2,5,3,3],
                     'C': [4,4,4,5,9,3,2,1]})
df
```

I want to create a new dataframe where for every column name will show the number of duplicates.

eg. `'B'`, has two values that are duplicated (9 and 3), I want to print 2 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1

if we need to calculate the number of duplicate values

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A': [1,2,3,3,2,4,5,3],
                     'B': [9,6,7,9,2,5,3,3],
                     'C': [4,4,4,5,9,3,2,1]})

df1 = df.apply(lambda x:sum(x.duplicated()))
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
A    3
B    2
C    2
dtype: int64
```

### Option 2

if we need to calculate the number of values that have duplicates

```
df1 = df.agg(lambda x: sum(x.value_counts() > 1)) # or df1 = df.apply(lambda x: sum(x.value_counts() > 1))
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
A    2
B    2
C    1
dtype: int64
```

### Option 2.1

detailed

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([f'[val = {i}, cnt = {v}]' for i, v in x.value_counts().iteritems() if v > 1]))
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
A    [val = 3, cnt = 3] [val = 2, cnt = 2]
B    [val = 9, cnt = 2] [val = 3, cnt = 2]
C                       [val = 4, cnt = 3]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you both for your contribution! The 2nd option is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want count duplicated by each element you can use this:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A': [1,2,3,3,2,4,5,3],
                     'B': [9,6,7,9,2,5,3,3],
                     'C': [4,4,4,5,9,3,2,1]})
def cnt(x):
    return {k:v for k,v in x.items() if v>1}
        

df.apply(lambda x : cnt(Counter(x)))
```

Output:

```
A    {2: 2, 3: 3}
B    {9: 2, 3: 2}
C          {4: 3}
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

- This can be done by getting the [`pandas.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for each column, and then get the [`pandas.Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) where the value count is greater than 1

  - `vc[vc.gt(1)]` creates a `pandas.Series` with the counts, for each value in a column, that're greater than 1.
- We can see from the `%%timeit` comparison for 5 columns of 1M rows, `.apply` with vectorized methods, as well as the `for-loop` and `dict-comprehension`, are faster than using `.apply` with built-in python [`sum(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

### `.apply` with `.value_counts` and `.sum`

- `col.value_counts().gt(1)` creates a `Boolean` Series

  - `True` evaluates as 1 and `False` as 0, so `.sum()` produces a correct result.

```py
dupe_count = df.agg(lambda col: col.value_counts().gt(1).sum())

A    2
B    2
C    1
dtype: int64
```

### `for-loop`

- It's not typically recommended to iterate through a dataframe, especially row-wise. However, we're iterating through the columns, and then applying a vectorized function, which is equivalent to what is happening with `.apply`.

```py
def col_vc(df):
    dupe_count = dict()
    for col in df.columns:
        dupe_count[col] = df[col].value_counts().gt(1).sum()
    return dupe_count


col_vc(df)

[result]:
{'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}
```

- The equivalent one-liner `dict-comprehension`

```py
dupe_count = {col: df[col].value_counts().gt(1).sum() for col in df.columns}

[result]:
{'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}

# to a dataframe if desired
dupe_count = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dupe_count, orient='index')

   0
A  2
B  2
C  1
```

### `%%timeit` comparison

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data 5 columns by 1M rows
np.random.seed(365)
rows = 1000000
data = {'a': np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=(rows)),
        'b': np.random.randint(15, 25000, size=(rows)),
        'c': np.random.randint(30, 40000, size=(rows)),
        'd': np.random.randint(450, 550000, size=(rows)),
        'e': np.random.randint(6000, 70000, size=(rows))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

- `.apply` with `.value_counts` and `.sum`

```py
%%timeit
df.agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().gt(1).sum())
[out]:
112 ms ± 1.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

- `dict-comprehension`

```py
%%timeit
{col: df[col].value_counts().gt(1).sum() for col in df.columns}
[out]:
111 ms ± 983 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

- `for-loop`

```py
%%timeit
col_vc(df)
[out]:
115 ms ± 4.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

- `.apply` with [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

```py
%%timeit
df.agg(lambda x: sum(x.value_counts() > 1))
[out]:
194 ms ± 17.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `collections.Counter` and `itertools.takewhile`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile
df.apply(lambda c: len(list(takewhile(lambda x: x[1]>1, Counter(c).most_common()))))
```

output:

```
A    2
B    2
C    1
```

If you want the output as a dataframe, add `.to_frame(name='n_duplicates')`:
output:

```
   n_duplicates
A             2
B             2
C             1
```

##### How it works

For each column, `Counter` gets the count of each element and `most_common` returns them with the most commons first.

`takewhile` iterates over this input and stops as soon as there is one element below the threshold (here 1).

Finally, we get the length of this output, which corresponds to the number of duplicated groups.